# node-cron will not run on a different folder

Tags: node.js, node-cron

I have a backend with nodejs, I have been using node-cron with out any issues, however, I was working on a new function that should run every day and when I test it worked. Then I add some more functions and for some reason they do not work anymore. If I test the cron on a different folder it works, but not on the one that I started working on, any ideas why this could happen? I know it works because I test something simple such as:

```
    cron.schedule('* * * * *', () => {
  console.log('running a task every minute');
});
```

In a different folder and I get the console.log() however on the other folder nothing happens. Is there a way to check why does not run on that specific folder? The path is controllers/folder.